# How to override QMessageBox blocking behavior?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have 2 blocking actions, one of them being QMessageBox `exec_` method. Second one is a `get_weight()` function that when it's executed it waits until user puts an item on a scale.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to inform the user with `QMessageBox` that he needs to do put an item on a scale and then get the weight of the item via `get_weight()`.

My problem is if I execute `exec_()` first, I'm unable to call `get_weight()` in parallel since `exec_()`is blocking. I could run `get_weight()` 1st in a separate thread, and then call `exec_()`, but I have no idea how to programatically close `QMessageBox`when a certain event happens.

Comment: That depends on what actually happens in `get_weight()`. What type of interface are you using for that scale?

Comment: @musicamante it basically does `readline()` which is blocking and will not return until it reads a line from COM port

Comment: Implement that thread in a QThread and emit a signal when it receives the right message, then connect that signal to the message box `close` slot. Note that Qt provides QSerialPort in the QtSerial module, which is already asynchronous.